# Barcode in pdf using PdfFileWriter

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm using PdfFileWriter to create pdf files and wants to add barcode on it, I used this code but it gives me dark rectangle barcode.

I tried to install font and use it, but the same problem faced me.

```
        Document = new PdfDocument(pageWidth, pageHieght, unitOfMeasure, FileName);
        PdfFont ArialNormal = new PdfFont(Document, "Arial", FontStyle.Regular, false);
        Page = new PdfPage(Document, pageWidth, pageHieght);

        Contents = new PdfContents(Page);
        Contents.SetColorNonStroking(Color.Black);
        BarcodeEAN13 Barcode1 = new BarcodeEAN13(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3 });
        Contents.DrawBarcode(PosX, PosY, TextJustify.Center, 40, 12, Barcode1, ArialNormal, 12);
```

Comment: What type of barcode are you trying to generate? Can you provide a screenshot of the barcode that this code generates? There are many different styles of barcodes (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Barcode&redirect=no#Symbologies) and it looks like PdfFileWriter only supports some of them (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570682/PDF-File-Writer-Csharp-Class-Library-Version#BarcodeSupport)

Comment: write Proper information.